# How specify two css classes: from property and conditional class

Tags: css, knockout.js, model-binding

I know that in knockout has the ability to specify class from observable property, like this:

```
<div data-bind="css: Color " >
```

Knockout also provides the ability to specify conditional class rendering like this:

```
<div data-bind="css: { 'my-class' : SomeBooleanProperty  }" >
```

**But which markup should be specified if i need those features of knockout css binding together?**

I tried this, but with no luck:

```
<div data-bind="css: { Color, 'my-class' : SomeBooleanProperty  }" >
```

I have got the error:

> Error: Unable to parse bindings. SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,;

I not found any example in google or in official docs.

**UPDATE**

I found a workaround: build up style string in code and put it to property, like this:

```
item.AdditionalCss(Color() + " " + (result.IsSortable() ? 'my-class' : null));
```

And specify this class in html:

```
data-bind="css: AdditionalCss "
```

But i little bit puzzled, i think it is dirty approach. I think it would be better to achieve the same result in markup. How can accomplish that with markup?

Comment: I'm not sure this works, but try `css: { Color : true, 'my-class': SomeBooleanProperty }`.

Comment: Thanks @Alxandr, but it not works, i have gotten markup: `class="Color my-class"`, but i need value of property **Color** instead of property name.

Comment: It is very sadly that knockout not provide same binding with 'data-bind' attribute only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [class binding](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Bindings---class)

```
<div data-bind="class: myClass" >
```

View model :

```
var vm = {
     myClass : ko.observableArray(),
};
vm.myClass.push('class1');
vm.myClass.push('class2');
```

You can also use the class binding with a computed.

But if you don't want to use it, you can do that :

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'class' :( Color() +  (SomeBooleanProperty() ? ' my-class' :'')) }">
```

Comment: Thanks, but i think it is same workaround which uses code, it would be nice if anyone give me example but with 'data-bind' markup only.

Comment: Thanks, attr-binding works nice, but same result it not provided by css-binding, it is very sadly. Thanks, you helped me.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a classic string formatting :

```
<div data-bind="css: Color() + (SomeBooleanProperty ? ' my-class' : '')" >
```

An example of this concept in action:

```js
var fullString = ('some' + ' ' + 'strings ') + 'and' + ' ' + 'other strings';
console.log(fullString);
```

Comment: This one worked for me, thank you very much! This is my code in case someone find it useful:

<li data-bind="css: slug + ((slug == $root.currentNav()) ? ' active' : '') ">

and the result is:

<li class="page1 active"></li>
<li class="page2"></li>
<li class="page3"></li>

Comment: i do not understand this code `Color()+(SomeBooleanProperty ? ' my-class' : '')` anyone would mind to explain. thanks