# Adding multiple classes with knockout css binding

Tags: css, knockout.js

I need to add two classes to an element using the css binding.

For example:

`<div class="animal" data-bind="css: mammal, dog"></div>`

However this only adds the first class, "mammal".

Please could you tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918300/how-specify-two-css-classes-from-property-and-conditional-class

Comment: `data-bind="css: {mammal:true, dog:true}"` or `data-bind="css: mammal, css: dog"` should both work.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
<div class="animal" data-bind="css: {mammal:true, dog:true}"></div>
```

See [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html)

Answer (score 6):

you can also use a string like this:

```
<div class="animal" data-bind="css:{'mammal dog':true}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to have a comma (,). just write with a space like below:

```
 <div data-bind="css:{'class1 class2 class3':true}"></div>
```